# R dplyr summarize_at: numeric vector of column positions results in "Can't convert a character NA to a symbol" - Summary stats output with t-test

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I wish to summarize a set of data in a dataframe using dplyer.

Concerning the "vars" argument, the documentation reads:

A list of columns generated by vars(), a character vector of column names, a numeric vector of column positions, or NULL.

I have the following behavior depending on the type of "vars" argument:

```
summarize_at(vars(D8,D9,D10), mean, na.rm=TRUE)     # works
summarize_at(c("D8","D9","D10"), mean, na.rm=TRUE)  # works
summarize_at(c(12,13,14), mean, na.rm=TRUE)         # Using column indexes for D8, D9 and D10, respectively
                                                    # ! Can't convert a character `NA` to a symbol.
summarize_at(c(12:14), mean, na.rm=TRUE)            # Same error as c(12,13,14)
```

Why I'm getting that error?

**POST EDIT**: *Adding data and actual code*

Data:

```
    # A tibble: 12 x 5
   TTMENT   DOSE    D8    D9   D10
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Group_1     0  40.3  41.1  41.5
 2 Group_1     0  37.4  36.9  37.1
 3 Group_1     0  44.8  44.1  44.4
 4 Group_2   450  39.6  39.6  39.4
 5 Group_2   450  40.6  41.2  40.8
 6 Group_2   450  41.1  42.1  41.2
 7 Group_3   500  38.5  39.2  39.9
 8 Group_3   500  41.6  41.6  41.5
 9 Group_3   500  41.8  41.8  42.4
10 Group_4   700  43.6  42    42.4
11 Group_4   700  43.1  42.7  42.7
12 Group_4   700  41.6  40.8  41.9
```

Error triggering code:

```
  group_by(TTMENT, DOSE) %>%
     #summarize_at(c("D8","D9","D10"), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
     #summarize_at(vars(D8,D9,D10), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
     summarize_at(c(3,4,5), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Full error:

Error in `FUN()`: ! Can't convert a character `NA` to a symbol. Backtrace:

1. stack %>% group_by(TTMENT, DOSE) %>% ...
2. dplyr::summarize_at(., c(3, 4, 5), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
3. dplyr:::manip_at(...)
4. dplyr:::tbl_at_syms(.tbl, .vars, .include_group_vars = .include_group_vars)
5. rlang::syms(vars)
6. rlang:::map(x, sym)
7. base::lapply(.x, .f, ...)
8. rlang FUN(X[[i]], ...)  Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :

I actually want an output showing mean, SD and SE presented in 3 rows per group (rather than in columns); and if possible an asterisk next to the mean in case of significant t-test between each group and the reference group (Group 1). Something like that:

```
Group    Statistic     D8    D9    D10
Group_1   Mean         XX    XX     XX
Group_1   SD           XX    XX     XX
Group_1   SE           XX    XX     XX
Group_2   Mean         XX*   XX     XX*
Group_2   SD           XX    XX     XX
Group_2   SE           XX    XX     XX
Group_3  etc.
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: I cannot replicate your error. E.g. if I try `library(dplyr); mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarize_at(c(1:2), sum)` I don't get an error. Neither with `c(1,2)`. Can you provide a reprex where we can reproduce the error?

Comment: Also some other thoughts: if `c("D8","D9","D10")` works, why not just go with it? And have you tried changing to `summarize(across(12:14, mean))` instead?

Comment: The most likely problem is that you're wrong about which column numbers have those names. Check `which(names(your_data) %in% c("D8","D9","D10"))`, is the result `12, 13, 14`?

Comment: And if you're still running into problems, post more of your pipeline. You say "there's a `group_by` before the `summarize_at`... is that all? Your output with multiple statistics makes me think you're doing multiple summaries, which could cause problems depending on how you do them.

Comment: Thanks jpiversen and Gregor Thomas. I have edited the post and added the data frame and the error. The data frame is just an extract. I have a significant amount of fields DX, where X is a number, so I'd like to use c(12:14) to select the columns, which also throws the same error.

Comment: @Pisuke You receive the error since the column numbers do not account for the 2 grouped columns. If you try `summarise_at` with 1:3 instead of 3:5 you will get your desired result. It would be preferable to use column names instead; and note that `summarise_at` is superceded by `across` in `dplyr`. Another consideration is to define a vector of names of columns based on column positions (and use this vector to indicates which columns to include in `summarise`), but it seems unnecessary, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3):

Just posting an answer as I found an explanation (newbie topic though...)

Apparently, by using group_by the columns used to group the data are extracted from the column indexes. Therefore, given the dataframe:

```
     # A tibble: 12 x 5
   TTMENT   DOSE    D8    D9   D10
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Group_1     0  40.3  41.1  41.5
 2 Group_1     0  37.4  36.9  37.1
 3 Group_1     0  44.8  44.1  44.4
 4 Group_2   450  39.6  39.6  39.4
 5 Group_2   450  40.6  41.2  40.8
 6 Group_2   450  41.1  42.1  41.2
 7 Group_3   500  38.5  39.2  39.9
 8 Group_3   500  41.6  41.6  41.5
 9 Group_3   500  41.8  41.8  42.4
10 Group_4   700  43.6  42    42.4
11 Group_4   700  43.1  42.7  42.7
12 Group_4   700  41.6  40.8  41.9
```

The following code **fails** as it assumes column indexes 3, 4 and 5 for columns D8, D9 and D10 respectively:

```
results <- stack %>%
  group_by(TTMENT, DOSE) %>%
  summarize_at(c(3:5), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Results in error:

```
Error in `FUN()`:
! Can't convert a character `NA` to a symbol.
```

In contrast, the following code provides the expected result, as it assumes column indexes 1, 2 and 3 for columns D8, D9 and D10 respectively. This is ignores TTMENT and DOSE for the index counting:

```
results <- stack %>%
  group_by(TTMENT, DOSE) %>%
  summarize_at(c(1:3), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   TTMENT [4]
  TTMENT   DOSE    D8    D9   D10
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Group_1     0  40.8  40.7  41  
2 Group_2   450  40.4  41.0  40.5
3 Group_3   500  40.6  40.9  41.3
4 Group_4   700  42.8  41.8  42.3
```

Thanks to @jpiversen, as his/her comment helped to understand what was going on.

Comment: In the code block that  *doesn't work* don't you mean `summarise_at(c(3:5))` instead of `summarise_at(c(1:3))`?

Comment: Thanks @ValeriVoev. Just corrected